# using jquery virtual keyboard on mac, special characters prints as ˜n instead of ñ in safari

Tags: jquery, macos, safari, special-characters, virtual-keyboard

so im using jquery virtual keyboard http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/

now checkout the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/

check it out using Safari on Mac

so normally in mac you can type in special characters using for instance `option + n` then n to print out ñ .... however if you click on the input field in that fiddle and then try to type in this special character at first you can do this to print the first ñ but then on second, third attempt afterwards pressing `option + n` would have its effect disappear immediately and if you then press n it ends up printing ˜n instead of ñ

any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer copied from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/298):

> You can solve this problem by disabling the useCombo option:
>
> ```
> $('#keyboard').keyboard({
>   // combos (emulate dead keys : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#US-International)
>   // if user inputs `a the script converts it to à, ^o becomes ô, etc.
>   useCombos : false
> });
> ```